# How to erase my iPhone photos completely?

Tags: iphone, ios, photos, photos.app

I decided to delete all of my iPhone's photos so I copied everything to iPhoto and deleted everything on my phone. But I still worry if somebody could recover my deleted photos from my iPhone? Does this method completely erase my photos on iPhone?

Answer (score 4):

Open **Albums** view in **Photos** by tapping the icon in the lower-right corner. Now find the album called **Recently Deleted** (it will have an icon with a circled trash can).

Open it, tap **Select** in the upper-right corner, then **Delete All** in the lower-left corner. Your photos will be permanently deleted from your iPhone.